# MAMP php file - how to run it from outside the server ( not local)

Tags: php, web, server, mamp

I have installed MAMP, and created a PHP file to the root of my installation ( c:\MAMP\htdocs) and to run I only use the url localhost/script.php in my browser. This works really niicely.
My question is:
Can I access this same file from the outside world through a browser (with my IP address)?

Comment: The answer is Yes, but you have to tell Apache that it is allowed to accept connections from ip addresses other than the local machine, open you firewall on port 80 and allow HTTP through your Router on port 80 and forward all port 80 comms on your router to the ip address of the PC running Apache

Comment: thank you for your help!